# Creating dynamically named fields in Solr without declaring a Transformer

Tags: mysql, jdbc, solr

I needed to index multiple fields from a table dynamically.  At first it didn't work, reading the field name as "_t".  Out of curiosity, I added a transformer declaration to the entity. This gave me the list of fields I needed.

**Why did adding a transformer that is never used fix my problem?**  Removing the transformer declaration causes the problem to come back, and it does not matter which transformer I declare.

I am running Solr 4.1, and this issue first happened to me on the included example-DIH example that came with the download. I read the Solr reference guide for 4.0, and could not find a reason why adding a transformer made it work.

Below is the db-data-config.xml file:

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource name="foo" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/foo"  user="fakeadmin" password="fakepass"/>
<document>
    <entity name="products" query="select * from `product`">
        <field name="id" column="id" />
        <entity name="names" query="select * from names where productId = '${products.id}'" transformer="LogTransformer">
            <field name="${names.fieldName}_t" column="fieldValue"/>
        </entity>
    </entity>
</document>
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. Especially if you see it in the example that came with 4.1. If you can easily reproduce it, might be worth [creating a bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR).

Comment: Made a bug report.  Thanks for the link.  The report can be seen here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4402